# Android add button

Tags: android

trying to add a button in android.

My sources look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startGame();
            }
        });

    }
    public void startGame()
    {

    }
```

and my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <Button style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/btnStartGame"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_game"
            android:onClick="startGame" />         
</LinearLayout>
```

The buton just simply doesnt appear!
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: And Of course, you could put the logcats here if there is an error or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have:

```
 android:onClick="startGame"
```

You don't need to use :

```
setOnClickListener
```

If you want to handle it with `setOnClickListener`, just use it like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartGame"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_game" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`android:onClick="startGame"` Removed.

That first problem has solved i guess.

You just need to use `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.softinspire.android.inspireball.DrawView
            android:id="@+id/draw_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bulletGreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="bullet_green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartGame"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="startGame"
            android:text="start_game" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnJoinGame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="joinGame"
            android:text="join_game" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlayWithComputer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playWithComputer"
            android:text="play_with_computer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStatistics"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="getStatistics"
            android:text="statistics" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateSession"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="createSession"
            android:text="create_session" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="getSettings"
            android:text="settings" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that android:onClick="startGame" is redundant since the button has a click listener in the java code. Hiwever, even if I removed the android:onClick="startGame" from the xml...or I kept android:onClick="startGame" in the xml and removed the listener from the java code...still no button. So I dont think this is the problem.

Comment: Everything is good right now, except you are doing that or refering the layout in the wrong way.could you please add more information?

Comment: Got it, that button is good on AndroidStudio Preview.which means, it's under the `Toolbar` if you have.you just need to change the position.

Comment: Perfect! Solved! Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome, you may want to take a look : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html please mark this answer if it solved your problem.goodluck

Answer (score 0):

```
       <Button 
        android:background="@yourstyle"
        android:id="@+id/btnStartGame"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_game"
        android:onClick="startGame" />
```

Please for mor information about android buttons click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)